# Element alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue aligning my elements.

I have elements that are appearing inside the others, like for example my paragraph with red background is above my image, and my second article is above my first article.

I have already tried many tests with floats but it's not working.

Do you see where the problem is?

Here is an example showing my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/2tsmX/3/

My html:

```
<div id="body_news">
    <div id="body-news1">
        <h1>News</h1> 
        <article id="news">
            <div class="img_container">
                <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
            </div>
            <h2><a href="#" >Títule Of the News</a></h2>
            <span>Date of the news</span>
            <p>text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
            </p>
        </article> 
        <article id="news">
            <div class="img_container">
                <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
            </div>   
            <h2><a href="#" >Títule Of the News</a></h2>
            <span>Date of the news</span>
            <p>text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
            </p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#body_news1
{
    float:left;
    width:480px;
}

#body_news1 h1
{
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:100;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.img_container
{
   width: 160px;
   height: 165px;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
   cursor: default;
   margin-right:20px; 
   border:3px solid #f3f3f3;
   margin-top:4px;   
}

#body_news
{
    width:480px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#news
{
    margin-bottom:5px; 
    position:relative;
    background:yellow;
     width:480px;
    text-align:left;
}

#news h2 a
{
    font-size:20px;  
    color:#000; 
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:0;
}

#news span 
{   
    font-size:14px; 
}

#news p
{
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background:red; 
}
```

Comment: Quick comment: change `id="news"` to `class="news"` since and ID must be unique

Comment: Not sure i understand. But if i do : You have to use position:absolute for that, and try different value of top and left for the element you want to position. Or maybe give us an draw of what you want

Comment: try giving display property to your news element.http://jsfiddle.net/2tsmX/5/. not sure if this is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

HTML

```
<div id="body_news">
    <div id="body-news1">
        <h1>News</h1> 
        <article class="news">
                <div class="img_container">
                    <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
                </div>
                <h2><a href="#" >Title Of the News</a></h2>
                <span>Date of the news</span>
                <p>
               text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
               </p>
         </article> 
          <article class="news">
                <div class="img_container">
                    <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
                </div>   
                <h2><a href="#" >Title Of the News</a></h2>
                <span>Date of the news</span>
                <p>
               text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
               </p>
        </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#body_news1
{
width:480px;
}

#body_news1 h1
{
font-size:25px;
font-weight:100;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.img_container
{
   width: 160px;
   height: 165px;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
   cursor: default;
   margin-right:20px; 
   border:3px solid #f3f3f3;
   margin-top:4px;   
}

#body_news
{
width:480px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.news
{
margin-bottom:5px; 
background:yellow;
    min-height:185px;
}

.news h2 a
{
font-size:20px;  
color:#000; 
text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:0;
}

.news span 
{   
font-size:14px; 
}

.news p
{
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
background:red; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tsmX/9/

Comment: Thanks, it was reaaly that Im trying to do! But why you need to have ain-height to news div?

Comment: @OzzC The `min-height` keeps the `.news` from being smaller then the `.img_container` and letting the image appear outside of the `.news` borders.

Comment: Thank you for your explanatior Biotox! By the way, its normal that the paragraph with red backround appears behind the image? Because it looks like if the image is inside the paragraph!

Comment: @OzzC Yes, it's normal because the image in floated next to the paragraph. You can just match the paragraph background to the `.news` background to keep them looking the same.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix - Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the `<span>Date of the news</span>`
of each div

Example:

```
<div id="body_news">
        <div id="body-news1">
            <h1>News</h1> 
            <article id="news">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
                    </div>
                    <h2><a href="#" >Títule Of the News</a></h2>
                    <span>Date of the news</span>
           <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!--HERE-->
                    <p>
                   text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
                   </p>
             </article> 
              <article id="news">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        <img  src="../image.jpg"/>        
                    </div>   
                    <h2><a href="#" >Títule Of the News</a></h2>
                    <span>Date of the news</span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div> <!--HERE-->
                    <p>
                   text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here text here 
                   </p>
            </article>
      </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2tsmX/8/)

Comment: Thanks, it was that I was trying but with paragraph below the date! Thanks!